# Javascript syntax to unbind double click behavior to an element

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript routine for ajax call, which works for the most part. I need to know the method of unbinding the click behavior to a div.

The structure of my routine is like this:

1. call ajax to search if the input is good or not, get response back from php. Result can be either Yes or No.
2. If result is Yes, change the color of a holder div as a visual cue, allow user to doubleclick on the div to run another function. If not, don't allow doubleclick div and don't run another function.

Easy right? Except that when the first ajax call yields a 'Yes' result, and then the user perform a second ajax call and it yields a 'No' result, the user can still dblclick on 'No' result and perform the action intended for a 'Yes' result. I have figured out that the initial 'Yes' result will assign the 'ondblclick' behavior to the holder div, and the follow up 'No' result does not have the code to unbind the div from dblclick behavior.  I have figured out how to unbind that 'dblclick' behavior using jquery.  But for reasons that is too long to explain (mainly due to having a '.' in id names), I need to use regular javascript to unbind.  What is the 'unbind' syntax using regular JS?

TIA

My code:

```
if (s == "Yes" ) { 

document.getElementById(divid).className = "tl1";
var data = result;

    document.getElementById(divid).ondblclick = function() {
    save (data);
    };
    //how to unbind divid from ondblclick using regular JS?
}
else {
//alert ("s is No");
document.getElementById(divid).className = "tl2";
         }
```

Comment: "mainly due to having a '.' in id names" - `$('#id\\.with\\.dots')` will get an element with an id of `id.with.dots`.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I have that in my other routines,  it is just that for this particular situation, I will need to reconvert back the escapes back and forth multiple times, it just seem more reasonable to keep things as JS for this situation.

Comment: _"for this particular situation, I will need to reconvert back the escapes back and forth multiple times"_ - why? You shouldn't have to pass `id`s around in your code. Can you show me an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: @Eric, the routine is being used by many ajax calls, so the divids are dynamically generated and I pass them to keep track and check for inconsistencies.  I don't want to post the whole routine. But more to the point, I know how to do this using jquery, and have done it.  This is just an academic question.

Comment: If the `div` `id`s are dynamically generated, then the `div`s themselves are available in your code. In that case, why not just pass around the `div` jQuery object, instead of the id? At any rate, you shouldn't have to select the object for a second time using `$('#'+messyEscapeOf(myId))`

Comment: Remember, if `id`s get messy, you can always do `$(document.getElementById(id))` to get a jQuery object from an id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and [`removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener). However, these only works in modern browsers.

Comment: Modern = IE9+ ? FF 1+, Chrome 1+, Safari 1+ and Opera 7+ support them. It's only IE that's retarded. Again.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it to work using jquery and myself's method. I am asking about this out of curiosity for a better alternative. It is always the little quirks in browser compatibility that cause most of the problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a dumb function or simple do:

```
document.getElementById(divid).ondblclick = null;
```

Comment: Hi myself, I have tried that too and it works, I intentionally left that out because I wanted to ask if there is an unbind equivalent for regular JS.